# Topology to Gateway Traffic from another Subnet

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ethernet, simulation

I am trying to configure a network topology (100 Mbit) to work with a hardware-in-the-loop simulation of a large-scale industrial simulation. In general, I would like to have the ECUs (left side) be blind to each other, and have all their inter-communication traffic routed through the simulator platform (marked with a star in the diagram below). I am able to configure up to 15 different IPs inside the simulator, and I also have much flexibility over the networking of the simulation machines (192 subnet, can be changed to anything).

[image: image of network topology]

The physical controllers in the loop are on the subnets 172.16.202.xxx and 172.16.4.xxx, while the simulation network is on the subnet 192.168.1.xxx. Using a cisco sg350x I am able to make the controllers blind to each other and forward their packets to a particular port on the switch. From there, I am using a dlink dsr250 in an attempt to NAT the controller traffic and force it to pass through the simulator. I have inbound/outbound rules in the router to change the source/destination addresses to either send to the simulator or make the outbound packets appear as if they have come from another real controller.

My issue is that this setup has yet to work. If I plug into a LAN port on the router, I can only see 192.168.xxx.xxx traffic, and nothing from the 172 subnet, even when I've configured the LAN side to be on that subnet as well (2 VLANs on LAN side of router). I've also set up IP aliases so that the controller-out traffic should be able to pass through the WAN port. What am I doing wrong?

some notes:

- the WAN is set to DHCP, but I'm not sure how I should configure it so
  that it will work properly, I think this is probably where my issue
  lies
- I can't change the addresses/MAC of the 172.xxx machines, they are production units that I can't tamper with, but all the 192 machines
  are fair game
- My expertise is in embedded controls and automotive integration, so
  my knowledge of the ethernet/networking world is pretty light, maybe
  this topology is impossible to achieve?
- Where those private, non routable ECUs end up (WAN or LAN) isn't important to me, I set up the network this way initially to seperate the networks functionally, but since I don't need actual internet connectivity, WAN in it's traditional sense isn't required. I know that most firewall/NAT rules apply when going between LAN and WAN, so this is where I thought i could apply the rules.
- ECUs need to talk to sim to get simulated data from the rest of the network (about 7 other ECUs running as models in the sim)
- due to hardware limitations, we only have 1 ethernet port in the simulator

Comment: Why do you have private, non routable addresses on your WAN side. As a lot of people use WAN to mean internet some clarification would be nice. Why should those ECUs talk to the simulator? Would the simulator do the routing?

Comment: 1.Where those private, non routable ECUs end up (WAN or LAN) isn't important to me, I set up the network this way initially to seperate the networks functionally, but since I don't need actual internet connectivity, WAN in it's traditional sense isn't required. I know that most firewall/NAT rules apply when going between LAN and WAN, so this is where I thought i could apply the rules.
2. ECUs need to talk to sim to get simulated data from the rest of the network (about 7 other ECUs running as models in the sim)
3. due to hardware limitations, we only have 1 ethernet port in the simulator

Comment: Add such context to your original question rather than keeping it in the comments. You have way more options that way to format it. You can setup any rule on any part of the network, the device you're using might be limiting it put that's an artificial limit. Why do you NAT the ECUs? Are the ECUs aware that they need to communicate with the simulator? What do the CISCO and dLink rules actually look like?